# Not able to get all the friends list who added photos in last 7 daysusing graph API

Tags: graph, facebook-rest-api

We are using following query to get all the friends list who have added photos to facebook for the last 7 days. It used to work previously but now it is not working it and only listing part of the users list with userId within range 1000000000 to 1200000000. But we have friends Id range from 1000000000 to 1500000000

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?access_token=[accessToken]&q=select uid, name from user where uid in (select owner from album where owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) and modified_major > now()-3600*24*7) ORDER BY name

Answer (score 0):

Adding more details to my question. I have around 17 friends who added photos in last  7 days. But above query returns only first 7 friends name only. If I give ranged query like https://graph.facebook.com/fql?access_token=[accessToken]&q=select uid, name from user where uid in (select owner from album where owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me() and uid2 > 12000000000 < uid2 1300000000) and modified_major > now()-3600*24*7) ORDER BY name.  It returns next set of 5 friends whose userids are between given range. Again udi2 >1300000000 and uid2 <1400000000 and it returned next 2 friends. I can't give paginated query in my application and my above mentioned query without range should return all the friends list. (It was working fine for more than one year and suddenly not been working for couple of months)